# Native Chrome and Windows 10 Audio Controllers for HTML5 Audio

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

How can I add these native Chrome and Windows 10 controllers to HTML5 music projects?

- "Next"
- "previous"
- "back a little"
- "forward a little"

Chrome:

[image]

Windows 10:

[image]

I searched but I can't find anything but play and pause.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is called the [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API).